# imap_mail_move, imap_mail_copy not working

Tags: php, imap

I am using PHP's IMAP function to redirect mail. I am using the function given in the documentation imap_mail_move, imap_mail_copy. but this is not working, it returns false.
the that i am using,

```
$mbox = '{'.$server.':'.$port.'/'.$tls.'}'.$mailbox;
$stream = imap_open($mbox,$username,$password);

$forward_mail_id = "mymail@gmail.com";
$msglist = "1,2,3";

$copy_status = imap_mail_move($stream , $msglist, $forward_mail_id);
```

but function returns false.
I want the mail in my webservers INBOX to be forwarded to my gmail's ID.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using TLS sessions, make sure that the connection is successful.
2. Try

   ```
   $copy_status = imap_mail_move($stream , $msglist, $forward_mail_id, CP_UID);
   ```

   `$msglist` then should consist of UIDs, not sequence numbers, of course.