# imap_mail_copy php error message

Tags: php, gmail-imap

I am trying copy messages from Inbox to another folder in Gmail using imap_mail_copy

I am able to connect to the mailbox fine and read in messages but I cannot move them without an error

```
if(!imap_mail_copy($connection,'$msg_num','[Gmail]/Starred', CP_UID))
        {
            echo "Didn't move messages number: $msg_num";
        }
imap_expunge($connection); 
imap_close($connection,CL_EXPUNGE);
```

Where $connection is the stream, $msg_num is read from the headers ($msg_num = $header->Msgno;) and Starred is the folder

The error is

```
PHP Notice:  Unknown: IMAP protocol error: Could not parse command (errflg=2) in 

Unknown on line 0
PHP Notice:  Unknown: Could not parse command (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Another thread about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262819/imap-mail-move-imap-mail-copy-not-working.  Btw, have you tried to copy to another directory ? Have you tried to use the same thing for another imap account (not google) ? (just trying to narrow down your problem :) ).

Comment: Have you tried exactly (without the CP_UID, and closing and expunging in one go?): imap_mail_copy($mbox,'16','[Gmail]/Starred'); // 16 is the message number, which can also be a range.(ex: '1:15')

imap_close($mbox,CL_EXPUNGE);

Comment: Removing the CP_UID has done the trick - thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

If `$msg_num` is a variable you need to feed to the function, you need to change your code to:

```
if(!imap_mail_copy($connection,"$msg_num",'[Gmail]/Starred', CP_UID))
```

or:

```
if(!imap_mail_copy($connection,$msg_num,'[Gmail]/Starred', CP_UID))
```

or (if you need to cast it to a string):

```
if(!imap_mail_copy($connection, (string) $msg_num,'[Gmail]/Starred', CP_UID))
```

Now you are literally sending the string `$msg_num`.

Comment: Good spot! Changed it but it doesn't seem to have resolved the issue. Any other ideas? Thanks!